# Generating Bernoulli Correlated Random Variables with Space Decaying Correlations

Tags: bernoulli-trial, st.statistics, pr.probability

Hi,

I have a set of N objects randomly distributed in a 2D physical space. Each object (i) generates a bernoulli random number (0 or 1) based on a marginal probability Pr(xi = 1) = p. These objects a correlated by physical distance. The closer the objects are, the larger their correlation is.

E.g. If objects i and j are co-located, they are expected to generate correlated results. For Example, if P(Xi=1)= 0.6 and P(Xj=1)=0.3 they would produce something like:

Xi= 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1

Xj= 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0

Such that Pr(Xi|Xj)=1

On the other hand if i and j are distant they would produce uncorrelated results such that
Pr(Xi|Xj)=Pr(Xi)

I have tried to use some of the packages in Matlab (Sampling from multivariate correlated binary and poisson random variables) and R (bindata) but I could not produce an acceptable correlation matrix.

Any ideas how I can produce an acceptable correlation matrix?

BTW, I have checked the following earlier posts [discrete stochastic process: exponentially correlated Bernoulli?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18268/discrete-stochastic-process-exponentially-correlated-bernoulli)

and

[Constructing Bernoulli random variables with prescribed correlation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19406/constructing-bernoulli-random-variables-with-prescribed-correlation)

But I am not sure how I can relate to them.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a suggestion:

Define a non-negative decreasing function $w(r)$ measuring interaction strength. Given each 
object its own independent $N(0,1)$ random variable $N_i$. Now set
$$
Y_i=\frac{\sum_{j}w(\|x_i-x_j\|)N_j}{\sqrt{\sum_j w(\|x_i-x_j\|)^2}},
$$
where $x_i$ denotes the location of the $i$th object.

Then the $Y_i$ are correlated $N(0,1)$ random variables. If two objects are co-located the normal random variables agree.

Finally set $t_i=\Phi^{-1}(p_i)$ (i.e. $\mathbb P(N < t_i)=p_i$) and set $X_i=1$ if $Y_i < p_i$ and 0 otherwise.

With this setup you can write down the covariance of $Y_i$ and $Y_k$ explicitly: it's just $$
\text{Cov}(Y_i,Y_k)=\frac{\sum_j w(\|x_i-x_j\|)w(\|x_k-x_j\|)}
{\sqrt{\sum_j w(\|x_i-x_j\|)^2\sum_j w(\|x_k-x_j\|)^2}}.
$$

If you write this as $\cos\theta_{ik}$ then you can write the covariance of $X_i$ and $X_k$ as an integral: 
$$
1/(2\pi)\int_{
x < t_1\;,\;
cos\theta_{ik}x+\sin\theta_{ik}y < t_2}
e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}\,dxdy-p_ip_k.
$$

Comment: If i understood you correctly, what you are saying is to simply use the Cov(Yi,Yk) above as the covariance matrix and plug it in the bernoulli generator. If so, then Unfortunately, I tried that but I keep getting an Unacceptable correlation matrix, which seams to be not positive definite. 

Comment: No you didn't understand me correctly. Here is my concrete suggestion. 
(1) Compute $t_i=\Phi^{-1}(p_i)$;
(2) Compute the matrix $Cov(Y_i,Y_k)$ as above
(3) Use a multivariate normal generator to build some $Y_i$'s. 
(4) Set $X_i=1$ if $Y_i<t_i$ and 0 otherwise.

You *could* compute the covariance of the Bernoulli's (using the nasty integral formula I wrote down), but if your purpose is to just generate the random #s, then the procedure I described will work just as well.

Comment: Acually, It is positive definite, but does not have a dichotomized Gaussian distribution for the correlation matrix.

Comment: OK, I think I understand your suggestion now. I will test it right away.

Comment: It works!, but I noticed that the Correlation (or Conditional Probabilities) $Pr(X{_i}=1|X{_k}=1)$ between any fixed pair (i and k) slightly change as we add more objects into the physical space.

So, I changed $Cov(Y{_i},Y{_k})$ to be $w(||x{_i}-x{_k}||)$ and it worked with fixed conditional probabilities, even if I add more objects. I am still testing it, but does this make sense to you?

For your information, my distance functions is $e^{(-\frac{eucaliandistance}{dcorr})}$

Comment: I guess this would work as long as the covariance matrix you get stays positive definite. I don't see any reason that it should in general, whereas the previous covariance matrix for the $Y$'s is always positive definite.